# Yii2 get access only using pretty URLs

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using URL manager like the following:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [                
                'verses/view/<id:\d+>' => 'verses/view',                
            ],
        ],
```

It works fine to make access using `mysite.com/verses/view/158`. The problem is, it is still possible to access the same content using non pretty URL i.e using plain get parameter such as `mysite.com/verses/view?id=158`. I need any way to restrict the access using the pretty URL.

I have tried the following couples of rules separately, but nothing I have gotten:

1. `'verses/view<?id=>' => 'Error404',`
2. `'verses/view?id=<\d+>' => 'Error404',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of such restriction?

Anyway, one way to do it is something like this:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if (strpos(\Yii::$app->request->getUrl(), '?') !== false) {
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
    }
    // ... the rest of action
}
```

No changes in UrlManager needed.

Comment: Also it may be generalized to all the controller's action by using this check in [`beforeAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UrlManager` parameter `enableStrictParsing = true`.

What happens. UrlManager checks all rulls and they all do not match the request. Thus, by default it checks all default rules. Among default rules it finds the rule with `?id=` and preforms routing to that one.

So, in order to avoid that route, you need to list all possible routes in the `UrlManger` rules and make `enableStrictParsing = true`. The routes not listed in the config `rules` parameter will be ignored.

Comment: This is good solution. However, it will be obligatory, to make very large rules list for every public action that the application has to be accessible. This will make things more complicated.

Comment: You just need to use more general rules like `<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>`